# need to reduce spinner font size and width

Tags: android

i need to reduce  the font size and width of spinner that means i need small spinner.below i copy the code of spinner.

my code:in main.xml:

```
<Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/fromSpinner"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"  
    android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"     
    android:prompt="@string/country_prompt"       
    android:entries="@array/from_spinner"/>
```

in strings.xml:Choose a Country

```
<string-array name="from_spinner">
  <item>Chennai</item>
  <item>Salem</item>
  <item>Delhi</item>
  <item>Mumbai</item>   
</string-array>  `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You will need to use a custom view and inflate it using an adapter to get full control.**

If you define the array in strings.xml and assign the entries you have limited control. You can have some control using HTML format in the XML itself.

For example: bolding an entry would be (this works)

```
<item><b>Chennai</b></item>
```

**I don't know if this will work for the size but try it out....**

```
<item><small>Chennai</small></item>
<item><big>Salem</big></item>
```

Comment: thanks, now i got small font size as well , but i tried  change font size via code using adapter i will not get small font size.so how can i use via java code

Comment: new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, your_spinner_layout ,list); your_spinner_layout is the custom xml layout

Answer (score 1):

The easier way is to change the your spinner items view when you are subclassing array adapter: don't use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`

Use

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets_array, R.layout.my_item_spinner_layout);
```

instead of

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets_array,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
```

`my_item_spinner_layout.xml` look like this for exemple

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:text="@+id/TextView01" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:textSize="18sp">
</TextView>
```

Comment: @user1500635 try it an let me know what you get

Comment: @user1500635 change your dataadapter  to this one:
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.my_item_spinner_layout,list) and this will work!!

Comment: @user1500635 In my_item_spinner_layout.xml set the appropriate size of text in textview

Comment: @user1500635 to tell other SO user what's the appropriate way if they face same problem ;)

Comment: @user1500635 you have to declare another layout as   told you it's the layout of your spinner item

Comment: i create a new layout named "trytry.xml",, but in setContentView i mentioned setContentView(R.layout.main); main.xml,, and below i submit my full code .Spinner spiner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner2);     
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
     list.add("list 1");
     list.add("list 2");
     list.add("list 3");      
     ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);         
     dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     spiner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);